# Rendering json as a table in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to render json data in a table using useState in react but it's not appearing for some reason.

This is the react file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import "../styling/Classes.css"
import data from "./mock-data.json";

function Classes() {
    const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
        { classCode: '', studentAmount: '' }
    ])
    
    const [students, setStudents] = useState(data)

    return (
        <div className="classes-container">
            <div className="classes-wrapper">
                <h2>Classes</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First name</th>
                            <th>Last name</th>
                            <th>Class code</th>
                            <th>Birth date</th>
                            <th>Mobile number</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {students.map((student) => {
                        <tr>
                            <td>{student.FirstName}</td>
                            <td>{student.LastName}</td>
                            <td>{student.ClassCode}</td>
                            <td>{student.BirthDate}</td>
                            <td>{student.MobileNumber}</td>
                        </tr>
                        })}
                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Classes;
```

This is the json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "FirstName": "Saif",
        "LastName": "Khadraoui",
        "ClassCode": "13-MA1",
        "BirthDate": "17/12/2003",
        "MobileNumber": "78464329843"
    },

    {
        "id": 1,
        "FirstName": "test1",
        "LastName": "Khadraoui",
        "ClassCode": "13-MA1",
        "BirthDate": "17/12/2003",
        "MobileNumber": "83427912"
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "FirstName": "test2",
        "LastName": "Khadraoui",
        "ClassCode": "13-MA1",
        "BirthDate": "17/12/2003",
        "MobileNumber": "316283216821"
    }
]
```

Comment: what do you see if you do console.log(data); console.log(students); just above the return statement ?

Comment: try printing data and see if first print undefined and later the currentData, it should be a sync problem

Comment: How do you import the json file and declare the data variable?

Comment: They both return the data as an array of objects

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos the json file is imported in line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```js
   {students.map((student) => {
       // You are not returning the part that should render
       <tr>
           <td>{student.FirstName}</td>
           <td>{student.LastName}</td>
           <td>{student.ClassCode}</td>
           <td>{student.BirthDate}</td>
           <td>{student.MobileNumber}</td>
       </tr>
    })}
```

```js
   {students.map((student) => {
       // Just return this part and it should render. 
       // Also don't forget to add a key for each tr
       return (
           <tr key={`${student.FirstName}-${student.LastName}`} >
               <td>{student.FirstName}</td>
               <td>{student.LastName}</td>
               <td>{student.ClassCode}</td>
               <td>{student.BirthDate}</td>
               <td>{student.MobileNumber}</td>
           </tr>
       );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning JSX only you can replace your curly brackets with parenthesis. Also, make sure to use a **unique** id for the iteration key, otherwise you are guaranteed to encounter sneaky bugs. You have ids in your data so let's use that:

```
{students.map(student => (
    <tr key={student.id}>
        <td>{student.FirstName}</td>
        <td>{student.LastName}</td>
        <td>{student.ClassCode}</td>
        <td>{student.BirthDate}</td>
        <td>{student.MobileNumber}</td>
    </tr>
)}
```